# Does test work the same as cmp?

Tags: x86, att

I'm wondering whether if the test instruction can be used the same as cmp. Let's say:

```
cmp %eax,%ebx
jg some_random_place
```

That jumps to some_random_place provided that %ebx is bigger than %eax, now if I do:

```
test %eax, %ebx
jg some_random_place
```

Under which conditions does that jump?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No!

The `cmp %eax,%ebx` instuction is like `sub %eax,%ebx` instruction, but with `cmp` instruction the registers after execution remain unchanged, except the flag register.

The `test %eax,%ebx` instuction is like `and %eax,%ebx` instruction, but with `test` instruction the registers after execution remain unchanged, except the flag register.
The affected flags are Carry = 0, Zero = x, Overflow=0 and Sign = x

The `jg` instructon should execute jump if zero flag = 0 and sign flag = overflow

So in case...

```
test %eax, %ebx
jg some_random_place
```

...the jump should be executed if the result of `and %eax,%ebx` is positive and not 0.

Comment: Thank you! I got to the flag part researching by myself after asking the question, but I couldnt unferstand how a binary and can raise an overflow flag, and still don't. Would you mind explaining that last part to me? Other than that, a preety good and clear answer!

Comment: `and` or `test` instruction never rise the overflow flag, but as I have written only clear after instruction execution.

Comment: Oh, so sign_flag = overflow can be translated into sign_flag equals zero, meaning that the number is positive, right? Now I got it!

Thank you